# Remove items from a Tuple list if already exists ignoring order c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, tuples

Hello I have a `List<Tuple<int, int>>` and I want to check if there are repeated elements no matter the order. So, for example, if my list contains

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> tuple = new List<Tuple<int, int>>()
{
     new Tuple<int, int>(1, 2),
     new Tuple<int, int>(2, 1),
     new Tuple<int, int>(3, 2)
};
```

I want to remove the the second item because it contains the same elements that the first but in reverse order (1,2) and (2,1).

What would be the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: Do you have problem to find the duplicate(s)?

Comment: How does this question relate to [tag:entity-framework]?

Answer (score 2):

```
var set = new HashSet<long>();
var unique = tuple.Where(t => set.Add((long)Math.Max(t.Item1, t.Item2) << 32 | Math.Min(t.Item1, t.Item2)))
```

If you are not iterating once then add `.ToList()` at the end

**update**

to remove from the original list

```
var set = new HashSet<long>();
for (int i = tuple.Count -1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (!set.Add((long)Math.Max(t.Item1, t.Item2) << 32 | Math.Min(t.Item1, t.Item2)))
        tuple.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Comment: I thought OP wanted to remove duplicates from the original list not create a new one.

Comment: Creating a filtered list is almost identical to remove from the original. But i can add that as well

Comment: It's not identical. Maybe you cannot re-assign the variable because that list was passed to you as a parameter and you have to manipulate it. Maybe there is somewhere a NotifyCollectionChanged listener on the original list.

Comment: Your update has a bug, you remove from the set and not from the tuple-list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DistinctBy` function:

```cs
var withoutDuplicates = tuple
    .DistinctBy(t => Tuple.Create(Math.Min(t.Item1, t.Item2), Math.Max(t.Item1, t.Item2)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: The same applies here, it will not work if OP has to remove them from the original list.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an [`IEqualityComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=net-7.0) and then you can use [Linq's `Distinct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-7.0) functionality:

```
var withoutDuplicate = tuple.Distinct(new IntegerTupleComparer()).ToList();
```

And here is a naive implementaion of the `IEqualityComparer<Tuple<int, int>>`

```
public class IntegerTupleComparer: IEqualityComparer<Tuple<int, int>>
{
    public bool Equals(Tuple<int, int> lhs, Tuple<int, int> rhs)
    {
        if (lhs == null && rhs == null)
           return true;
        if (lhs == null || rhs == null)
           return false;
         
        return GetHashCode(rhs).Equals(GetHashCode(lhs));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Tuple<int, int> _)
        => _.Item1.GetHashCode() + _.Item2.GetHashCode();
}
```

[Working example on dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/P6gz68)